# use object in c#.net, like vb.net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have a method in VB.Net that calls button of form:

```
Private Sub BUTTON_CAL( _
    ByVal frm As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs)

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.A AndAlso e.Modifiers = Keys.Control Then
        If frm.AddButton.Enabled = True Then Call frm.AddButton.PerformClick()
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
    End if
End Sub
```

I have converted this code into c#

```
public static void BUTTON_CAL(object frm, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e) {
    if(e.KeyCode==Keys.A&&e.Modifiers==Keys.Control) {
        if(frm.AddButton.Enabled==true) {
            frm.AddButton.PerformClick();
        }
        e.SuppressKeyPress=true;
    }
}
```

in C#.Net I am getting the error

> 'object' does not contain a definition for AddButton' and no extension method 'AddButton' accepting a first agument of type 'object' could be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You need to cast `frm` to it's actual type. Show where you call this method.

Comment: frm is System.Windows.Forms

Comment: @TimSchmelter `BUTTON_CAL(object frm ...`

Comment: Do type casting: frm as System.Windows.Forms. But, i think System.Windows.Forms do not contain method/property AddButton

Comment: if `frm` is the same form on which the button you are clicking, remove the `frm.` i.e. you don't need to qualify `AddButton` with `frm.` if both the method exists on same form.

Comment: Side-note: you should really set [`OPTION STRICT on`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9341s4f(v=vs.110).aspx) in VB.NET as well. Also, `Call` is a redundant statement.

Comment: there are multiple forms that have multiple buttons and all call this method on keydown event.

Comment: Another possibility (which doesn't deserve an answer because it encourages excessive late binding) would be to declare `frm` as `dynamic` instead of as `object`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cast 'frm' to the data type you expect it to be (runtime checking if valid is a good idea)

```
Form form = frm as Form;

if( null == form )
    // error

form.AddButton(...);
```

Comment: If you're going to throw an error if it's null, just cast instead - it'll be simpler code, and give a clear exception. Also, there's no reason to use `if (null == form)` rather than `if (form == null)` in C#. It's not like the typo of `if (form = null)` would compile.

Comment: Yeah, old habits from C++ die hard ;)

Comment: System.Windows.Forms does not contain the definition for 'AddButton' ... How to implement ????

Comment: @MandeepSingh "Cast 'frm' to the data type you expect it to be" states the answer. `Form` is just an example

Comment: The event handler's first parameter is of type "object".  If you want access to any of the members of the object passed in as that parameter, you'll need to cast it to a more specific type.

Comment: You can not use even one form if it does not have AddButton property. The solution can be to create in interface `IAddingButton{ SomeType AddButton {get; set;} } `, inherit all the forms from this interface and cast to it `IAddingButton form = frm as IAddingButton;`

Comment: This answer is a little bit misleading since `Form` is absolutely the wrong type. `Form` is a class in the .NET framework which clearly has no `AddButton` method. But OP has created a class which derives from `Form` (`MyCustomForm`) and added a method ` `AddButton` there. He need to cast the object to this type to be able to use this method. @Moho: You should edit it and add what Jon +  Dmitry mentioned and use a different type.

Comment: @TimSchmelter You're right, but I think `AddButton` is not a method, but a simple `Button` :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void BUTTON_CAL(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    if(sender is Form) {
        var frm=sender as Form;

        if(e.KeyCode==Keys.A && e.Modifiers==Keys.Control) {
            if(frm.AddButton.Enabled)
                frm.AddButton.PerformClick();

            e.SuppressKeyPress=true;
        }
    }
}
```

1. The signature of `KeyEventHandler` is

   ```
   public delegate void KeyEventHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e);
   ```
2. Rather `if(SomeBool)` than `if(SomeBool==true)`. Don't be unnecessarily complicated.
3. put `someObject as SomeType` in a `if(someObject is SomeType)` would be safe. It seems a little bit redundant, but more readable than compare to null.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you all for giving time to solve the problem
I have solved the problem by using below :

```
public static void BUTTON_CAL(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e) 
{
     var frm = sender as Form;

     if(e.KeyCode==Keys.A&&e.Modifiers==Keys.Control) 
     {  
          if(frm.Controls["AddButton"].Enabled==true)
          {
             ((Button)frm.Controls["AddButton"]).PerformClick();
          }
          e.SuppressKeyPress=true;
     }
}
```

Comment: You really should accept one of the proposed answer, instead of writing your (redundant) one.

Comment: The original question was how to use Object in C# the same way it can be used in VB. IMHO, this answer is the only one that tries to do some kind of "duck typing" as VB allows so it is not redundant. In fact, other answers were only half complete since they missed that part.

Answer (score -2):

cast frm to the class name of your form

```
if (((Form1)frm).AddButton.Enabled == true){
   ((Form1)frm).AddButton.PerformClick();
}
```

I assume Form1 is the name of your form, and it has a button with name AddButton and that button has the proper access modifier.

Comment: Forms.Form does not have AddButton field or property. -1